# MySQL: Update same row multiple times in one query with values from another table

Tags: mysql

Given the following table structures:

T1:

```
id a
1  1
2  2
3  3
```

T2:

```
id t1_id b
1  1     1
2  1     2
3  2     3
```

I need to add the value of `t2.b` to the value of `t1.a` where `t2.t1_id = t1.id`.

A simple update with a join like the following isn't working:

```
UPDATE t1
  JOIN t2 
    ON t2.t1_id = t1.id
   SET t1.a = t1.a + t2.b
 WHERE t2.id IN(1,2)
```

Expected T1 result (adds 1 and 2 to t1.a = 1; 3 to t1.a = 2):

```
id a
1  4
2  5
3  3
```

Actual T1 result (only adds 1 to t1.a = 1; 3 to t1.a = 2):

```
id a
1  2
2  5
3  3
```

At the moment I'm looking at a select that computes the full sum of values to be added using a `group by`, and then that result set is joined to the update... This  seems like overkill for something so simple though! Does anyone have an elegant and efficient solution?

Comment: I think moving the join into a subselect at where clause should do the trick.

Comment: Problem is you have a one to many relationship from T1 - T2. You would only be adding an arbitrary single row from table 2 to the value from table 1. I can't think of a straight Join method of doing this off the top of my head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Came up with this real quickly.

```
UPDATE T1 AS t
JOIN (
    SELECT
        t1_id, SUM(b) AS sum_total
    FROM
        T2
    WHERE
        t1_id IN (1, 2)
    GROUP BY
        T2.t1_id
) AS t2 ON t.id = t2.t1_id
SET  t.a =  t.a + t2.sum_total;
```

Comment: Yeah that's the structure I had come to as well, was wondering if there's a 'nicer' way. Thanks!